# How can I get TypeScript to infer the type of a prop if generic is a union?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to write a function that can take a generic which is a union and then add/change properties on that generic and return the updated type.

The problem is that when trying to change a property that already exists on all the types in the union TS cannot infer that it must be only one of the union instead of all of them.

This is an example of what I'm trying to do. I would expect that using `field.sharedProp` wouldn't error because it must be the same type as `T['sharedProp']`, but TS cannot seem to infer that and errors because it thinks it could be `OneOfInterfaces['sharedProp']`.

```
interface IA {
    sharedProp: { a: string }
}
interface IB {
    sharedProp: { b: string }
}
interface IC {
    sharedProp: { c: string }
}

type OneOfInterfaces = IA | IB | IC
type GenericTest<T extends OneOfInterfaces> = T & {
    otherProp: string
}

function test<T extends OneOfInterfaces> (field: T): GenericTest<T> {
    return {
        ...field,
        sharedProp: field.sharedProp, // <-- TS2322 here, removing this line works
        otherProp: ''
    }
}
```

My actual use case isn't this simple, what I'm trying to do is run the `sharedProp` through a function to add some extra properties but the error is the same.

Is there a way to rewrite this in a way that TS would be able to figure this out without doing something like wrapping this in a switch case or similar to discriminate the union?

[Here is a playground with the above code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.4#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIEFkG8BQz-IDOAFnFBACYAKUA9gA4Bc2yczhYUoA5sgL44BoSLEQpUAIWx4CJMpRoNmWZACN2nHv0E5h0eEjQBhaQSKly1OkxYINXELwECcYAJ70UAeRAQvMVHB9MUJkAF40TAAfNCkY1CNXDxQAcQhfLgQAFQgOAB4s5AgAD0gQClCfPwCg0SRCAD5w5EKAMlMCWjBiaEUbDgduHRwYAFcQBDBgWhBkSHzCkrKK5Cr-QJEDXKaAChhgCAAbCmYsgEpmNIzgbNywAqbcM3IwUahZp7MCADpf-aOKAAaGRfczyKxKZD-Y7fOSWPqA5AAeiRyDyAFp0S0AMoAJgAzLjccgeuREeQALa0ABuWm6wFCh1AKAA7rQoABrQggr5dUl9ZgAckFPOcOCAA)

Edit: [Here's another example with nested properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.4#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIEFkG8BQz-IDOAFnFBACYAKUA9gA4Bc2yczhYUoA5gDRGlyFAHIQOlZiACuAWwBG0ZAF8cK0JFiIUqAELY8BEmUo0GzLMjntOPfkaGjxFSbIVRlqnOujwkaAML6BALG1HRMLAjWXCB8IQ5ikM7I0vKKKio4YACe9CgA8iAQ+TCo4D5ahMgAvGiYAD5oeo2o-lm5KADiEEVcCAAqiQA8-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). It seems that if you run each prop being modified through a generic function it can work, I still don't understand why this is the case though.

Comment: Is [this code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.4#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIEFkG8BQz-IDOAFnFBACYAKUA9gA4Bc2yczhYUoA5sgL44BoSLEQpUAIWx4CJMpRoNmWZACN2nHv0E5h0eEjQBhaQSKly1OkxYINXELwECcYAJ70UAeRAQvMVHB9MUJkAF40TAAfNCkY1CNXDxQAcQhfLgQAFQgOAB4s5AgAD0gQClCfPwCg0SRCAD5w5EKAMlMCWjBiaEUbDgduHRwYAFcQBDBgWhBkSHzCkrKK5Cr-QJEDXKaAChhgCAAbCmYsgEpmNIzgbNywAqbcMwQZjmRi5o6zfAA6P-2jhQADQyb7meRWJTIAHHH5ySx9IHIAD0yOQeQAtBiWgBlABMAGY8XjkD1yEjyABbWgANy03WAoUOoBQAHdaFAANaEUHfLpkvrMADkQt5fAA3LzyGBRlBZsVJS4XiA3gAvZrzMA7J6yCwKazKXlmdTIIWoViU2KiszOM7IHBAA) enough to solve your problem?

Comment: @Lesziak That's such a weird fix, why does assigning it to a variable make any difference? In my case it doesn't help because I'm passing these props through some functions and the type check fails on those function calls too.